# Referencing a question

Tags: cross-referencing

How to reference a response to question that is the number is formatted as: 1.j)?

Is it?

Please refer to the response to question 1.j.

or

Please refer to the response to question 1.j).

Comment: I would ask this on [english.se].

Answer (score 1):

I favour the former, but I'd opt for

> Please refer to the response to question (1.j).

Comment: Thank you for responding - this is helpful!  As a follow-up, even if there was no opening parenthesis, you would include (1.j.)?

Comment: Yes, that's my proposal. It's all about readability and that's the easiest (subjective) to read. (I think there was some discussion on this site recently about a similar issue, but I can't think of suitable search terms to dig it up.)

Comment: Possibly this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107958/academic-writing-numbered-points-in-text-etiquette?noredirect=1&lq=1?